# Roots of line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, divisors

Let $k$ be a fixed algebraically closed field and $X/k$ an irreducible scheme smooth and proper over $k$. Can there exist a line bundles $\mathcal{L}, \mathcal{M}$ and an integer $m > 0$ so that

1.) $\dim_k \Gamma(\mathcal{L}) = 0$

2.) $\dim_k \Gamma(\mathcal{M}) > 0$

With $\mathcal{L}^m \cong \mathcal{M}^m$. If not, does an example exist if you drop smoothness (then replace $\mathcal{M}$ with the line bundle of an effective Weil divisor) or the condition that $k$ is algebraically closed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Take $\mathcal L$ the trivial line bundle, with a one-dimensional space of global sections, and $\mathcal M$ a nontrivial torsion line bundle, so $\mathcal M^k=\mathcal L$.

Then $\Gamma(\mathcal M)$ is certainly zero-dimensional, since otherwise $\mathcal M$ would have a nonvanishing section and be trivial or a somewhere vanishing section and then $\mathcal L$ would have a somewhere vanishing section and be nontrivial.

This provides a counterexample. Such examples exist on any smooth proper variety with a nontrivial Picard variety, meaning $\operatorname{dim}_kH^1(X,\mathcal O_X)>0$, such as curves of positive genus.

Comment: Great, Thanks! Are there also non-torsion examples?

Comment: Yes. Take a curve of genus $2$ or higher, then most degree $1$ line bundles have a zero-dimensional space of global sections. Take the $n$th tensor power of this line bundle for $n\geq g$. Now it has degree $n$ and so a positive-dimensional space, by Riemann-Roch. 

Comment: What is $\mathcal{M}$ in your example?

Comment: Oh great, I made a serious typo in my question. The $n$ was supposed to be an $m$. I just corrected it. Are there still non-torsion examples?

Comment: Yes. Take a curve of genus $g\geq 2$. Then the space of line bundles of degree $1$ is a complex torus of dimension $g$. The space of line bundles which have a nontrivial global section is the image of the curve under the map sending a point to the line bundle corresponding to its divisor, so has dimension $1$. Fix one such line bundle. Now consider all the line bundles that are it tensor a torsion line bundle. These correspond to translations of the torus by torsion points on its Jacobian, so these points are dense, so at least one of them does not have a nontrivial global section.

Comment: $\mathcal M$ being the original line bundle, $\mathcal N$ being the second, and $m$ being the order of the torsion line bundle you tensored by.

Comment: It is not too hard to see by counting that $m=2$ suffices on a hyperelliptic curve. If $f$ is the hyperelliptic projection to $\mathbb P^1$ there are $2g+2$ points such that `$\mathcal O(P)^{\otimes 2}=f^*\mathcal O(1)$`, but there $2^{2g}$ degree $1$ divisors such that $\mathcal L^{\otimes 2} =f^* \mathcal O(1)$, so there must be one line bundle of that form with a nontrivial global section and one line bundle of that form without a nontrivial global section.

Comment: Excellent answer! Why are there $2p+2$ points as above?

Comment: Because those are exactly the ramification points of $f$. It has $2g+2$ ramification points by Riemann-Hurwitz. As to why they must be ramification points, it's because if $\mathcal O(P)^{\otimes 2}=f^* \mathcal O(1)$, then there is a global section of $f^* \mathcal O(1)$ with divisor $2P$, so a section of $\mathcal O(1)$ whose divisor pulled back is $2P$, so a point on $\mathbb P^1$ whose inverse image is $2P$, so $P$ is a ramification point.

Comment: Great. Is it clear that the divisor of zeroes of any $s \in \Gamma f^*\mathcal{O}(1)$ is the pullback of a divisor from $\mathbb{P}^1$? If you know a reference for this fact in more generality I'd love to see it.

Comment: If there were any more global sections you would get a degree $2$ map to $\mathbb P^2$, which makes your curve a conic in $\mathbb P^2$, which makes it rational. I guess this is a special case of Clifford's Theorem (Hartshorne 4.5.4) + Riemann-Roch: By Clifford's theorem, if $f^* \mathcal O(1)$ is special then the dimension of the space of global sections is at most $2/2+1=2$. On the other hand if it's general then the dimension of the space of global sections is $2+1-g=3-g\leq 1$. So the dimension of the space of global sections is exactly $2$, so all of them come from the pullback.

Comment: Another thing to generalize it from is Lemma 4.5.1, which says the canonical linear system has no base points, plus Riemann-Roch, to show the dimension of the space of global sections of divisor of degree $d>0$ on a curve of genus $g\geq 2$ is at most $d$.

Comment: Great thanks! Incidentally, I thought you had a different sort of argument in mind.

Comment: Unfortunately I think that the obvious sort of argument would be false. I don't know any general condition implying that, for $f:X \to Y$ and $\mathcal L$ on $Y$, $f^* \Gamma(Y, \mathcal L)=\Gamma(X,f^* \mathcal L)$.